# Acessar uma variável fora do escopo da classe vai contra os princípios SOLID?

Tags: javascript, classes, solid

```
const clients = [{ username: "test" }]; 


class Validator {
  constructor(username){
    this.username = username;
  }

  isUsernameTaken(username) {
    let usernames = [];
    clients.forEach((e) => usernames.push(e.username)); //Acessando variável fora do escopo
    return usernames.includes(username);
  }
}
```

Se isso for uma má prática, qual seria o melhor jeito de fazer isso, dado que a variável `clients` deverá ser usada por mais de uma classe?

Comment: Como estou sem tempo pra responder, vou comentar o que eu aprendi. A recomendacao é que deve se  evitar uso de var globais, pois pode ocorrer de ser dificil garantir que outros módulos, classes, funcoes, etc... não irão modificar essa var global. Porém, cheguei a ler em artigos que pode se usar var globais, desde que essas sejam __estáticas__, ou seja, somente leitura e que não sejam possíveis de serem modificadas... Posso estar enganado, mas vou esperar alguem mais expert pra falar sobre isso nas respostas.... Acho que o uso delas estaria infringindo o `S` e/ou `O` do __SOLID__.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como bem observado na pergunta, o princípio do "Open/close" do "SOLID" pode ir na contra-mão do uso de membros de escopo global ou públicos (`public` na maioria das linguagens).

O que diz o princípio do "Open/close"?

> In object-oriented programming, the open–closed principle states
> *"software entities (classes, modules, functions, etc.) should be open
> for extension, but closed for modification"*

Fonte: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle

Em tradução livre:

> Na programação orientada a objetos, o princípio aberto-fechado afirma
> *"entidades de software (classes, módulos, funções, etc.) devem ser
> abertas para extensão, mas fechadas para modificação"*

Primeiro vamos analisar o seu exemplo:

```
clients.forEach((e) => usernames.push(e.username)); //Acessando variável fora do escopo
```

O que importa é, para respeitar o princípio do *Open/close*, nós devemos garantir que esse método possa ser extensível, mas não mudar "modificar o original" por assim dizer.

Se nós estendermos esse método e pudermos alterar a variável `clients`, isso pode afetar o comportamento de outros componentes que utilizem essa variável, porque ela tem um escopo maior que o método ou a classe, então nós iríamos violar o princípio.

Uma vez que é uma contante, não há possibilidade dela ser alterada, então **no seu exemplo** isso está aderente ao princípio.

Como o @CmteCardeal havia comentado, se um membro tem um escopo fora da classe, é porque queremos partilhar entre várias partes do código, então ele **deve ser imutável**, uma constante por exemplo, possivelmente estáticas quando possível, mas o mais importante é que não permitam mudança. Note que, o fato de ser simplesmente `static` não garante que não pode ser mudada, é preciso proteger usando uma `const` ou com encapsulamento.

Classes com *resources* são um bom exemplo, por exemplo mensagens e strings que são usadas dentro de toda a aplicação, que devem ser constantes.

Portanto, não é o acessar a variável que vai contra os princípios, mas a variável permitir mudanças, sendo de escopo fora da classe é quem iria contra o princípio.